# Replace text in a list with tuples

Tags: python, list, replace, tuples

This is my first question here, I'm learning python and trying to solve the following problem:

Using the CX_oracle library I execute an SQL query. 
The results are returned in a list, which has tuples in it for all rows that the query returns. I've saved it in a variable called "data". 
Below an example of one row.

```
[('tuple_item_1','tuple_item_2', 'this\nis\none\nstring\nwith\nlinebrakes')]
```

What I would like to do is search the initial tuple for the '\n' and replace it with a space character in the new tuple. I know that a tuple itself can't be modified. The purpose of this is to output it to a csv file without the linebreaks so it can be interpreted by some tools.

I will appreciate your help very much. 
Thank you in advance.

```
def querydata(): #create function
sql = 'select * from db1' #sql statement
cursor.execute(sql) #cursor
headers = [row[0] for row in cursor.description] #column names saved into variable 'headers'
data = cursor.fetchall() #all returned data saved into variable 'data'
data2 = ["" if s == "\n" else None for s in data]
return data2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> data = [('tuple_item_1','tuple_item_2', 'this\nis\none\nstring\nwith\nlinebrakes')]
>>> data2 = [tuple(item.replace('\n', ' ') for item in row) for row in data]
>>> data2
[('tuple_item_1', 'tuple_item_2', 'this is one string with linebrakes')]
```